# solution space of nonhomogeneous system is not a subspace of $K^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $Ax = b$ is a nonhomogeneous system of linear equations in $n$
> unknowns. Then, the solution set is $\mathbf{not}$ a subspace of
> $K^n$.

### Thought:

Let $W = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : Ax = b \}$ be the solution set. Since $b \neq 0$, then $x$ cannot be the trivial solution. Thus, the zero vector is not in $W$, and consequently, it cannot be a subspace of $K^n$.

Is this correct or do I need to show more? It seems so simple that I feel as Im missing something here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You are right ! You are missing nothing. Since $b \ne 0$, we have $ 0 \notin W$. Hence $W$ is not a subspace of $ \mathbb K^n$.