# In $Ax = b$, why does $x$ not pass through the origin?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I am facing some difficulty in understanding the concept of $x$ being a vector which doesn't pass through the origin.

Let me tell you what I understand:

- A subspace is a space that contains all linear combinations of a vector and it passes through the origin.
- $Ax = b$, $A$ is invertible and $b$ is the set of solutions for $x$ vector of unknowns.

In Prof. Gilbert Strang's book, there is a mention of the following. Any vector $x_n$ in the null space can be added to a particular solution $x_p$. The solutions to all linear equations have this form, $x = x_p +x_n$:

***Complete solution $Ax_p = b$ and $Ax_n = 0$ produce $A(x_p +x_n) = b$.***

So is this, complete solution, a plane? It certainly is a vector space because all linear combinations of A result in b and if so, then it should pass through the origin.

If my understanding of a vector space is correct, then why does $x$ not pass through the origin?

Please feel free to correct me wherever you feel necessary, I am unable to understand this at all. It is quite impossible for $x$ to be 0 and $b$ to be non-zero at the same time yet the idea of the vector space, origin and null space is a bit confusing for me.

Comment: This probably belongs on math.SE or similar instead of here, but might need some more focus anyway.  A few comments: b is not the set of solutions, you're after the set of solutions, i.e. the values of x that satisfy the equation; a vector cannot "pass through the origin"; the solution set is not a vector space generally, because as you point out 0 is generally not a solution, nor is it closed under addition (it is an _affine_ set); the decomposition of the solution set into particular solutions and the null space of A is useful for finding and expressing all the solutions

Comment: "A subspace is a space that contains all linear combinations of a vector and it passes through the origin." Thats not the definition of a subspace!

Answer (score 1):

> It certainly is a vector space

No, it isn't. Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be two solutions of $Ax=b$. Then, $A(x_1+x_2)=Ax_1+Ax_2 = b+b=2b \neq b$.

In case $b=0$, the set of solutions to $Ax=0$ is indeed a vector subspace (the nullspace of $A$).

Answer (score 1):

**Claim**: Suppose the system $Ax = b$ has a particular solution $x_p$. Then the set $S$ of all solutions to $Ax = b$ equals $x_p + N(A)$, where $N(A)$ is the nullspace of $A$. (Here the notation $x_p + N(A)$ means the set $\{ x_p + n: n \in N(A) \}$.)

**Proof**: To prove that the sets are equal, we show containment in both directions.

$S \subseteq x_p + N(A)$: Let $s$ be an arbitrary element of $S$; in other words, $As = b$. Since $Ax_p = b$ as well, we have $As = Ax_p$. Hence $As - Ax_p = 0$, i.e. $A(s - x_p) = 0$. So $s - x_p \in N(A)$, which means that $s - x_p = n$ for some $n \in N(A)$. So $s = x_p + n \in x_p \in N(A)$, as desired.

$x_p + N(A) \subseteq S$: Let $x_p + n$ (where $n \in N(A)$) be an arbitrary element of $x_p + N(A)$. Then $A(x_p + n) = Ax_p + An = b + 0 = b$, so that $x_p + n$ solves the system $Ax = b$; in other words, $x_p + n \in S$, as desired. $\square$

Geometrically, the set of solutions to the consistent system $Ax = b$ is parallel to the nullspace (which is the set of solutions to $Ax = 0$). This is what $x_p + N(A)$ means geometrically: take all the vectors in the nullspace and translate them by the vector $x_p$. So, for example, if the nullspace is a plane in 3D, then the set of solutions to the consistent system $Ax = b$ is another plane parallel to it.

Comment: I have a few more follow-up questions:
So the complete solution contains both the null space and the set of solutions. The set of solutions remain parallel to the null space, so is that why $x$ can't pass through the null space for any non-null values of $b$?
Also, the column space of Ax contains the solutions to b, so that column space is a subspace isn't it? If so, then is $b$(set of solutions) subspace too?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by "contains both the null space and the set of solutions", or "$x$ can't pass through the null space for any non-null values of $b$". And the column space does not (in general) contain the solutions to the system $Ax = b$. The set of solutions is a subset of the domain, while the column space is a subset of the codomain.

Comment: The column space is a subspace of the codomain, while the set of solutions to $Ax = b$ is not a subspace unless $b = 0$. This is because if $b \neq 0$, then for $x = 0$, we have $Ax = A(0) = 0 \neq b$, so $0$ is not a solution to the system. Since the set of solutions does not contain $0$, it cannot be a subspace.

Comment: I may have interpreted the lingo wrong, sorry for the confusion but what I mean to say is the same as you have mentioned here - ${x_p+n:n∈N(A)} $. I guess my doubt has been cleared now. Thank you.

Comment: Actually I was referring the vector x as a line which passes through the origin, I tried to mention "passing through" in that context.

Comment: Regarding your first comment: It is not true that "the complete solution contains both the null space and the set of solutions". I am not sure what that even means. When Strang says "complete solution", I believe he just means that every solution to the system $Ax = b$ can be written as a sum of $x_p$ and $x_n$, where $x_p$ is a particular solution and $x_n$ is in the nullspace.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2064301/solution-space-of-nonhomogeneous-system-is-not-a-subspace-of-kn This was the question which was contradicting my not so smooth understanding of this concept. Hope you will be able to understand why I was asking those questions. Thanks for your patience.